# How to extract certificates from a time-stamp response in Bouncy Castle

Tags: c#, bouncycastle, rfc3161

Using Bouncy Castle and C#, I am requesting a timestamp token with the certificates included (`timestampRequestGenerator.SetCertReq(true)`) and I get a response significantly bigger than when setting `SetCertReq` to `false`, so I assume that the response has *somewhere* the public key certificates used to generate the timestamp.

How can I access those certificates using Bouncy Castle? I have explored the response object in Visual Studio but did not find where the certificates are.

```
Stream inputFile = File.OpenRead("response-with-certs.tsr");
TimeStampResponse response = new TimeStampResponse(inputFile);
inputFile.Close();
```

Comment: Supposedly (after looking here: https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/pkixdocs1.4/org/bouncycastle/tsp/TimeStampResponse.html) there would be an `Encoded` property or `GetEncoded()` method. If you capture that (using `Convert.ToBase64String`) we can inspect the asn1 together to check where the certs are.

Comment: Actually found some sample code here: https://www.digistamp.com/toolkitDoc/comNetToolkit/DigiStampCS.txt

So you should be able to do `response.TimeStampToken.GetCertificates("Collection")` to get the cert collection out

Comment: Thank you @zaitsman, it worked. If you want, please can you write it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you should be able to retrieve the certificate collection like so:

```
response.TimeStampToken.GetCertificates("Collection");
```